# Git can't switch to or delete a branch

Tags: git, branch

In git, I named a branch `2020`. I now can't switch to that branch, and when I try to delete it, I get the error `fatal: branch name required`. I have tried the regular `git branch -d 2020` and the force `git branch -D 2020`.

I have also tried placing the branch name in quotes, but I get the same error.

I don't want this branch any more, is there anything that can be done?

UPDATE: I can checkout the branch using `git checkout refs/heads/2020`, but I cannot delete it by doing the same.

UPDATE 2: Navigating to .git/refs/ then renaming 2020 to 2020s allowed me to delete it. Whatever git was playing at, I have no idea.

Comment: Does `git branch` show your branch listed?

Comment: It shows it in the list as a branch, yes.

Comment: If it is listed try and rename the branch and delete again

Comment: git branch -m [old_name] [new_name]

Comment: I just created a branch with that name, and deleted it. Got deleted successfully, with the same command you're running. Something else seems to be wrong.

Comment: @gpullen I tried to rename it, and it created a new branch and left the old one.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `2020` looks like an abbreviated SHA-1.

I've done this sort of thing before myself, with what look like words: I had a branch I named `cafe` or similar.

The trick is to put some non-numeric, non-"a through f" character into the branch name (you can rename it with `git branch -m` rather than the low level method you used) so that git can tell it's not an SHA-1.

Comment: I up-voted because it explained why this happened, however the solution you provided didn't work for me. Git couldn't rename the branch. Thanks though :)

Comment: No doubt you no longer have the problem :-) but what happened when you attempted `git branch -m 2020 2020s`?  (Ah, I see above: you got a `2020s` and yet `2020` lived on.  That's weird, when I try the same it just renames it.)

Comment: When the tool I am using refuses to do what I am asking, I resort to old-fashioned methods :p To me, it still seems strange, but it's all sorted now. Lesson learned, use better naming conventions!

Answer (score 0):

Navigating to .git/refs/ then renaming 2020 to 2020s allowed me to delete it.

I still have no idea what caused this, or if there was another remedy, but it appears to have been sorted.